# How to balance quickness and redundancy in MongoDB data structures?

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a MongoDB database with a *users* collection (with *UserFiles* in it) and a *posts* collection. Each post has *tags* and *sharedFrom* fields in it. I eventually plan to have users' search results influenced by what tags they normally post about and from which other users they often share posts. Would it be better to:

1. make a field in the UserFile document of each user that lists the post IDs made by the user?
2. make a field in the UserFile that documents that lists all the *tags* they have used and other users that they have *sharedFrom*?
3. make the search function look up the searchers activity that then influences the search results?
4. something I haven't thought of?

Comment: What exactly is "UserFiles"? You say within the UsaerFile document but what is this document? Where does it reside? Is it a subdocument of a user document?

Comment: A "UserFile" is the type of document that I am putting in the _users_ collection. The UserFile has all the basic info such as email, ID, username and demographic info. I am basically wondering whether I should add activities records to the UserFile documents or not.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't, I am gonna go out on a limb here and say that activites is like a fb wall describing shared posts by tags demographics. This spounds like a unbound array able to grow to any size and might even get enough traffic to grow outside of the max document size

Comment: Yes, it is basically like the fb wall you described. So you are saying that it would be better to do something like my option 3 above?

Comment: Yeah, roughly like that. The description is a little brief but I think you got the right idea there

Comment: Ok, thanks. For time and attention's sake didn't want to get lost in the full detail of everything I was doing because just wanted to make sure I was going in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to go, if you have a question about the details then you can come back